# Insert image from Google drive into sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to insert image into sheet. However, it keeps return `Error retrieving image from URL or bad URL`. The `webContentLink` method works normally. It return a link with `&export=download`. I even tried to truncate that and insert image but still get the same error. Many of the image files have the public-anyone can see sharing setting.

I have tried many ways to insert image but none is working. Some answers about this were about 3-4 years ago so I just have to ask again to make sure. I have tried function `IMAGE` in sheet but it often load the image very slowly (often 10s of minutes after entering the function). I also tried `blob` method but to no avail. It returns the strange error that I don't know how to handle `a server error occurred`. The function works normally for other files, working with files in Google Drive is very very difficult. I am at my wit's end, please help.

```
function insertImg()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var currentCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var thisFileId = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  var thisFile = DriveApp.getFileById(thisFileId);
  var folder = thisFile.getParents().next(); 

  var files = folder.getFiles(); 
  var i =0;  
  while (files.hasNext())
  {
    var file = files.next();
    if (file.getMimeType()== 'image/jpeg')
    {
     i++;
     var img = Drive.Files.get(file.getId()).webContentLink;
     sheet.insertImage(img, 1, i);  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the share permission on the file like so? `file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW)` add this line inside the if block!

Comment: Yes, that was it. Please put it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Also,why `;` is not needed at the end? I don't have it and it works fine.